# BooleanConvert: Boolean decision tree

Tags: boolean-computation, logic, reference-request

The [BooleanConvert](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/BooleanConvert.html) function includes an available form called "Boolean decision tree": BDT.

1. What is the formal logical definition of a Boolean decision tree as used here?
2. What is the algorithm for computing it?